# arxiv uploading problem: Undefined control sequence. <argument> \@currentauthors

Tags: pdftex, undefined

No problem appear when I use local pdflatex to compile.

Here's the log output by arxiv.

```
[verbose]: Creating arXiv submission AutoTeX object
[verbose]: *** Using TeX Live 2020 ***
[verbose]: Calling arXiv submission AutoTeX process
[verbose]: TeX/AutoTeX.pm: admin_timeout = minion
[verbose]: <acmart.cls> is of type 'TeX auxiliary'.
...
[verbose]: <named.bst> is of type 'TeX auxiliary'.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Processing file 'kdd-arxiv.tex'
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running pdflatex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2020/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/4346183/ && pdflatex 'kdd-arxiv.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./kdd-arxiv.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-09-06> (./acmart.cls
Document Class: acmart 2022/05/10 v1.85 Typesetting articles for the Associatio
n for Computing Machinery
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
...
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/subfigure/subfigure.sty
****************************************
* Local config file subfigure.cfg used *
****************************************
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/subfigure/subfigure.cfg))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/multicol.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/multirow/multirow.sty)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/makecell/makecell.sty
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty))
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/preprint/balance.sty)
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \@currentauthors

l.110 \begin{document}

?
! Emergency stop.
<argument> \@currentauthors

l.110 \begin{document}

! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on kdd-arxiv.log.
```

### Update

Minimal error reproduce code:

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}
\acmYear{2022}

\title{XXX}

\author{XXX}
% !!! no error occurs without next line
\authornote{Both authors contributed equally to this research.}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{XXX}
  \city{XXX}
  \state{XXX}
  \country{XXX}}
\email{XXX}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
XXXX
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please write a minimal working example. See [link](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/250119) for more details what it means.

Comment: Although you probably just needed to specify the author name.

Comment: Welcome. // Please understand that without having your code, in this case at least the whole preamble and a few lines after \begin{document}, hardly anybody can give you useful advice.

Comment: @MS-SPO Sorry for that. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @user202729, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved the problem by checking the official [Association for Computing Machinery (ACM) - SIG Proceedings Template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/association-for-computing-machinery-acm-sig-proceedings-template/bmvfhcdnxfty).

The problem was solved by simply moving the title and authors to the "document" block.

But I still don't know exactly what the problem is, and why it doesn't have any problem compiling locally, but only happens on arxiv. If anyone has any clue, please let me know. I really appreciate it.